# RBAC for single application on WebSphere App Server

Tags: authorization, websphere, rbac

I want to use a role based access control for the authorization of one of the applications on a WebSphere application server, but as far as I've seen the users and roles are defined on application server level, and not for a single application. Is it right, or in case it isn't could you please tell me how the define the roles in for my application?

The problem with declaring the roles on server level is that there are multiple independent applications on the server.

Answer (score 0):

1) To do this kind of role based mapping you need to have security enabled in WAS.
2) After you installed your application, open the admin console of WebSphere Application Server. List the installed application, click on your application. You should find a link called "Security role to user/group mapping". The wizard will then guide you to map the role you want to the application.